# Trying to change data with the UPDATE function in SQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-update

I'm using PHP, and with the update-function I'm trying to change data in SQL.

Can anyone show me how that's done?

Answer (score 2):

Look to http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp